# Is restore from backup broken?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am unable to restore data from a backup. The [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin.html) is not helpful. There is no way to "select the backup" and there are no "Restore" clickables on the "Datastore Admin" page. The backup is in "Completed" status.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working and testing a lot on back up and restore. One issue I had is the Data store Admin tag on the admin page did display the page properly. If you have an issue copy the url of the page and open in another browser IE, chrome or everyone you have.  It has to allow permission to be used by your user.

Worth a try